# How to remove the "Webpage Dialog" in IE modal window title?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using `window.showmodaldialog()` in javascript.

In modal dialog "webpage dialog" content is appended in the title. I want to remove this. 
I tried to force to space after title. Also I don't want to use " ". Any other way to remove this?

[image: Modal window - webpage dialog]

Comment: show us your code ? what have you tried ? Without that its extremely difficult to respond ..

Comment: how to add long blank space in html head tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The "Webpage Dialog" suffix is added specifically to try to prevent `showModalDialog()` from being used to spoof native UI.

You're probably best off avoiding `showModalDialog()` and using an in-page dialog (similar to the image upload dialog on Stack Overflow) instead, as that's more widely supported, and **much** more flexible.

Comment: how to add long blank space in html head tag?